# No Search form for custom theme

Tags: 7, theming, blocks, search

I am creating my first theme.  I don't see the "Search form" block under structure>block for my theme.  It is present for other themes.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Should I put something the the .info file to enable it?
NB: I am working with Drupal 7.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything special within your theme to enable the search form block. If that block is available in other themes, there is no reason it would not be available in your theme. Have you carefully checked the list of disabled blocks for your theme to make sure the search form block is not located in that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that there was nothing wrong with my theme.  I installed the theme in a new installation of drupal and the search block was available.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in that it was not showing up under Structure -> Blocks. I found it under Dashboard as a block. I then enabled it for my theme by configuring the search form block in the Dashboard. It then shows up under Structure -> Blocks.